# How to list the available econdings of a webcam?

Tags: webcam, gstreamer

is there a way for discovering all the available encodings of a certain webcam (e.g x-raw-rgb -xraw-yuv)?

Morevoer, I would like to discover also the available resolutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, set the v4l2src element to ready and check the caps on the src pad. The element will narrow the list of caps down to the ones actually supported when it has opened and queried an actual device. That happens in READY state.

Comment: Thanks,do you have a link or some source code please? Thanks again!

Comment: All gstreamer modules have tests/examples directories. Have a look there (gst-plugin-good for v4l2 and gst-plugin-bad for camerabin). You might also want to look at the sources for cheese/empaty as the use gstreamer with v4l2.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is the following (command line):

```
GST_DEBUG=v4l2src:3 gst-launch v4l2src ! decodebin2 ! xvimagesink
```

If the video source in onboard else change the "v4l2src". This will show ALOT of info, from "probed caps:" it will long line of possible formats the video source supports.

Here is a same copy/paste from my machine:

> probed caps: video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)YUY2, width=(int)1280,
>   height=(int)720, interlaced=(boolean)false,
>   pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction){ 10/1 };
>   video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)YUY2, width=(int)640, height=(int)480,
>   interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1,
>   framerate=(fraction){ 30/1 };
>   So the info your looking for is:

```
! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=30/1, width=640, height=480, interlaced=false !
```

If anything NOT from the probed list will result in error:
**could not negotiate format**

Comment: seems different with gst-launch-1.0